# Array Index Out of Bounds when creating Buffered Image in Java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am attempting to process an image file and return it as an Image object, however I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the following code when I call  public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(int[] data, int columns, int rows).

I have the following pixel colors stored into an array named "data":

```
[255,6,65,78,99,100,25,0,45,66,88,190,88,76,50]
```

I parsed this out from a text file that looked like this:

```
255, 6, 65, 78, 99
100, 25, 0, 45, 66
88, 190, 88, 76, 50
```

I am trying to generate an image from this data by using [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.htm) currently I am hitting a brick wall with this. Columns and rows are passed to this based on the table structure above.

```
    public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(int[] data, int columns, int rows) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(columns, rows, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    raster.setPixels(0,0, columns, rows, data);
    image.setData(raster);
    return image;
}
```

I get an OOB exception when I hit the raster.setPixels call. Does this need a different array or value I am missing?

Comment: An AIOOBException will be thrown by [WritableRaster#setPixels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setPixels%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[]%29) if "if the coordinates are not in bounds, or if iArray is too small to hold the input."  You can eliminate the first cause, and therefore deduce that the `data` array is smaller in size than `columns*rows`.  I recommend debugging your values.

Comment: Within the WriteableRaster I do see maxX = 5 and maxY = 3 being set within raster, I am unclear of how to set this array to the appropriate size.

Comment: Why a downvote, I dont get it ? Its a valid question and well written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found, the type RGB requires 3 bands... therefore to create an array that works:

```
private int[] imageArray(String fullFilePath, int rows, int columns) throws Exception{
    int picRows = rows;
    int picColumns = columns;
    data = getPixelData(fullFilePath);

    //3 bands in TYPE_INT_RGB
    int NUM_BANDS = 3;
    int[] arrayImage = new int[picRows * picColumns * NUM_BANDS];

    for (int i = 0; i < picRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < picColumns; j++) {
            for (int band = 0; band < NUM_BANDS; band++)
                for (int k = 0; k < data.length; k++)
                    arrayImage[((i * picRows) + j)*NUM_BANDS + band] = data[k];
        }
    }
    return arrayImage;
}
```